# Updating automatic comment on Github when changing commit message

Tags: git, github

When I a create a pull request, a comment is automatically created which is the same as the commit message.

If I edit the commmit message through my terminal, `git commit --ammend` and then force push, I see the commit message changes as expected on Github.

However, this original comment does not change. Is there a way to configure it to do so? Or must I continue to copy-paste my updates to the commit message here?

Here is a screenshot for what I'm talking about:

[image]

This was automatically created with the content from my initial commit message, but even though the message has been since edited it does not update.

Comment: Having dealt with this before, I don't think it's possible. One option is to contact GitHub ─ I've found they're incredibly helpful, and quickly as well.

Comment: If updating PRs via `git commit --amend` so drastically that the PR description must change is something you do so often that it's a hassle to edit the description via the web UI, you might want to consider how you're using PRs. I'd question why you have to `git commit --amend` after you've pushed and created the PR so often. A follow up question might be to describe your current process and whether it can be improved.

Comment: @Schwern I amend the commit because I want to change it but have it be a single commit. It works fine except for this particular issue, which is only a minor annoyance. What are you suggesting I do instead?

Comment: @maxpleaner If it's an occasional thing, update the PR via the web UI. GitHub using your commit message for the PR description is a convenience feature, it's better than nothing. It's not really supposed to track the commit message changing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a PR, GitHub takes the last commit message as PR's title.
That comment is auto-generated because the PR title is much longer that its input section width.

Changing the commit message via `commit --amend` then `push -f` will not change the PR title.

Try to change it via the UI; if that comment is not changed with the new PR title content(it should be a longer one too), then I consider this as a bug in GitHub.